# Read Facebook private messages from bash terminal?

Tags: facebook, terminal, mutt

I'm a long-timed Mutt user. Is there a way to read, delete and reply to Facebook private messages in mutt-like style, from a bash Ubuntu/Debian terminal?

Thanks

Comment: This is not programming-related.

Comment: Well, it could be...

You need some script starring wget/curl and a lot of parsing to load the messages via HTTP. But maybe some captcha comes in your way, or fb changes the page-layout... then you're doomed

Comment: Few edits above and also, facebook has not got email addresses for us.. That there says that facebook is either adding email support or they only want to receive mail to your account, but don't want to you use another email client like mutt.. In other words FB has email addresses that you can email, so they should have a way to set this up in an email client such as mutt

Answer (score 2):

Please take a look at https://sites.google.com/a/dtompkins.com/fbcmd/ the [`INBOX`](http://fbcmd.dtompkins.com/commands/inbox) command does exactly what you need

Answer (score 0):

Try http://kissrobber.github.io/facebook_client_terminal/
The command to do what you want is `api me/inbox`

To setup this in your Ubuntu/Debian terminal, go to https://github.com/kissrobber/facebook_client_terminal